# CSS cleanup positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

Im have a little trouble finishing up my home page for a site.

site: [www.crookednosebeer.com](http://www.crookednosebeer.com)

if you go to the home page it looks exactly how it should, but when you scroll down to the footer the main background follows and so does the beer bottle. I just want those things to stay where they are at, and for the beer bottle to be right on top of the footer where it is cut off.

css:

```
body{
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
background-color: #b2b2b2;
background: url(../images/trial3.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*HERE iS BOTTLE IMAGE */
.smoke {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}

#footer{
height: 125px;
background: #333333;
width: 100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned Scroll Down, i cant scroll down when i go to your site

Comment: I can't even scroll the page, and the footer appears about 1/3 up from the bottom of the page

Comment: yes, you need to take into account larger screen resolutions mine is 1680px by 1050px go to browserstack use a mac and check your site in a larger screen

Comment: @ConnorMiles What should i do?

Comment: Sorry, just got your message, well to get started jump over to http://browserstack.com/ create a free account and when your in there you can view your website in all different browsers and machines, when you got the feel of it change the OS to a mac and underneath you will see screen resolutions, change them accordingly and view your site, reason i say mac is because on that site mac OS have bigger screen resolutions you can view in, if your site is really bad in larger and smaller screens you should look into media queries at this link, http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/,

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the word `fixed` from your body's `background` property and your `.smoke` class.

### Edit

I think I figured it out. I'm running Chrome, and I tried it in Firefox 15 and IE8. They all seem to work the way you're asking for when you add `position:absolute` to the `.smoke` class and `position:relative` to the `#footer` div.

You can play around with my [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/WXxnk/3/), and [here's the result](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/WXxnk/3/show/).

Comment: You should probably pull the logo off the background and position it up higher. It's getting cut off on my laptop.

Comment: This fixes the background image on the `body` element but not the bottle (bottom right).

Comment: Ah, it's called `.smoke`, not `.bottle`. Anyway, the `fixed` property is preventing scrolling.  Did you mean `position:absolute`?

Comment: @AustinMullins I did what you said and now it works like i asked, however i am getting a difference in appearance in browsers.

I just want the bottle to be positioned on top of the footer in every browser, its above it in firefox, but below it in chrome.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I can look at it some more in about an hour. Chrome and IE are interpreting `bottom:0` as meaning the bottom of the window, not the div. I like Firefox's interpretation better, but there is a way to make it work for all. I just can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @AustinMullins  I added relative to the footer, and changed my main div as AliGreen suggested. Now the bottle image covers up the contact link and in chrome the footer is lifted 25px above the bottom of the page, but the bottle picture does not cover up contact link

Comment: The image won't cover anything if you give it a `z-index:-1`. With `position:relative`, the footer will start after the end of the `#main` div, so its exact position depends on the height of your content.

Comment: @AustinMullins Thanks!! i think the first draft is ready for publish now

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm up to [version 19 on the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/WXxnk/19/show/) by the way. I added a spacer div to `#main` to push the footer down farther, but it really depends on the user's browser resolution where everything will land.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `position:relative` on your `#main DIV` and change `width:1350px` to `width:100%`, that'll fix your vertical scrollbar issue too!

Comment: I added relative to the footer, and changed my main div as you suggested. Now the bottle image covers up the contact link and in chrome the footer is lifted 25px above the bottom of the page, but the bottle picture does not cover up contact link